# Is it possible to use my desktop pc's webcam with the hololens 2 emulator?

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

is there a way to use my webcam within the hololens 2 emulator to capture images/videos?
I'm currently trying to develop an app with unity + hololens 2 emulator and i've googled the entire internet without finding an answer.

Basically what i'm saying is "can i see what my webcam sees through the emulator?"

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible.  We are investigating the possibility of adding this in a future update.

Comment: Why is it not possible? It's because hololens has it's own "camera set" ?

Comment: This is not possible mainly because the work to enable it was not done.  There is no technical reason that basic webcam input does not work.  More advanced scenarios involving depth data will require creative solutions, as standard desktop webcams do not have this.